# How to retrieve list of multi selected items from ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-select, listcollectionview

How do I get the list of selected items from a ListCollectionView?  I see CurrentItem returns for single selection but I don't see anything to return the list of selected items in multi-select mode.

Answer (score 2):

`ListCollectionView` or other types implementing `ICollectionView` are wrapper over source collection which WPF creates internally to bind with instead of direct binding to source collection. So, it does not have any such property to get selected items on GUI which is more or less a UI thing.

You need to get the SelectedItems from an UI component. `ListCollectionView` must be binded to `ListBox`. **Access ListBox [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get selected items on view**.

Comment: afaik SelectedItems is no DP and so you can not bind to it. but you can use it as a commandparameter like CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lsv, Path=SelectedItems}"